# Cross browser question about HTML 5 doctype

Tags: html, cross-browser

Can I use the HTML 5 doctype in older browsers like IE 8 or 7? If not what would be a good method to handle cross browser compatibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of people use and recommend the open source [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) javascript library to handle these issues. You can code for HTML5 and **modernizr** will try to gracefully degrade for features not supported by the user's browser. As they say:

> Taking advantage of the new
> capabilities of HTML5 and CSS3 can
> mean sacrificing control over the
> experience in older browsers.
> Modernizr 2 is your starting point for
> making the best websites and
> applications that work exactly right
> no matter what browser or device your
> visitors use.

It is high-quality enough to be used by Google, Microsoft, The Economist, About.com, The Knot, Good and Posterous.